# Operate with my line and next line in data frame with R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've a data frame like this:

```
A tibble: 693,748 x 10
   Target Orbit CrossSectionalArea Elevation  RAAN ObsType Observer           StartTime            StopTime  Duration
   <fctr> <int>             <fctr>     <int> <int>  <fctr>   <fctr>              <dttm>              <dttm>     <dbl>
1   Sat1   550                Ama         5     0       A      AV1 2019-09-01 20:47:50 2019-09-01 20:49:14  84.22333
2   Sat1   550                Ama         5     0       A      AV1 2019-09-03 09:54:27 2019-09-03 09:55:49  82.45977
3   Sat1   550                Ama         5     0       A      AV1 2019-09-04 09:45:37 2019-09-04 09:47:41 124.05633
```

I'm trying to create a new column with `mutate` where `newcolumn` has `StopTime - StartTime(next row)`. My problem is when I try to get `StartTime(next row)`.

How can I do this operation?

Thank you!

Comment: `dplyr::lead` will work.

Comment: @cluna IN the last row, do you need NA or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(newcolumn = StopTime  -  lead(StartTime))
```